# Alternatives to java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet

Tags: java, android, multithreading, collections

I'm looking at porting some code that uses java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet to an environment where this class is not available (specifically, android 2.2).  I'm therefore looking for alternatives to it.  My requirements are:

- basic 'Set' implementation (don't need NavigableSet or similar)
- standard operations must be thread safe (I don't have a high call volume, so locking is acceptable)
- iterators must not throw ConcurrentModificationException
- iterators must support the remove() operation

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried just copying the source for ConcurrentSkipListSet and see if it works in Android 2.2? You have the JDK5 basics of the concurreny classes working there, right?

Comment: This could be doable, but is likely to be some work, as ConcurrentSkipListSet seems to use package-private methods of other java.util.concurrent classes.  I don't know how many classes I would end up having to copy.  I was hoping there were alternative implementations out there that would do the job, but if there aren't, I guess this is the best way forward.

Comment: Although looking at the source for ConcurrentSkipListSet reminded me of something I'd noticed before: the source for HashSet (http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/HashSet.java.htm) is extremely simple, and uses a HashMap to perform all of its work. I wonder if copying this and substituting a ConcurrentHashMap will do what I want?

Comment: No, you'd need a ConcurrentSkipListMap for your snapshot-copy-iterators. That's not in Android 2.2 either.

Comment: It does appear to work with a ConcurrentHashMap.  My test for concurrent modification passes with this, but not with a HashMap, so it's certainly doing something to allow the Iterators to work.

Comment: It does seem (as per JavaDoc) like ConcurrentHashMap's iterators also never throw ConcurrentModificationExceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a backport of java.util.concurrent for JDK 1.3 and above](http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/). It includes ConcurrentSkipListSet. Give that a try. You probably want the version for JDK 5.

Comment: Useful.  And if I'd seen it before implementing my own solution (as per the comments on the original question) I'd be using it now!

Answer (score -1):

Use a HashSet:

```
 Set s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet(...));
```

Synchronize on s and this should work as long as you are not modifying the set in any way other than the by using the Iterator remove() operation.

[Collections.synchronizedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet%28java.util.Set%29)

Comment: This won't work as I have one thread iterating on the contents of the set while another simultaneously adds items.

Comment: But you said locking was acceptable! :p j/k. I think you might try Thilo's recommendation in that case.